# Turbolinks Throws Uncaught TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am a newbie for Ruby on Rails programming. Recently, I am using Rails 5.2.3 with turbolinks attached. Several days ago the turbolinks seems working fine. However, recently it throws the error of "Uncaught TypeError: window.scrollTo is not a function." I would like to know the alternatives of this problem.

I have tried rearranging the javascript orders of load but it does not seem to fix the issues

Here are the application.js files that I have

```
//= require jquery3
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require cocoon
//= require underscore/underscore
//= require smoothscroll-polyfill/dist/smoothscroll
//= require sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min
//= require_tree .
```

and the order I have on my application.html.erb

```html
<head>
    ...
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    ...

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/rails-gmaps' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/rails-ujs-sweetalert2' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/popper' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/tooltip' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/owlcarousel2/dist/owl.carousel.min' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/cleave-js/dist/cleave.min' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/select2/dist/js/select2.min' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/mtr-datepicker/mtr-datepicker.min' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/modules/chart.min' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/owl' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/dashboard' %>


    <%= javascript_include_tag 'sub/custom' %>
  </head>
```

Would like to know what would be the cause of window.scrollTo error on turbolinks. Because the error causes all of the javascript not to be loaded properly. Thank you very much